# Pytorch: Adding a dimension to a tensor through padding

Tags: pytorch, padding, tensor, zero-padding

I have given different tensors where some have only 2 dimensions and some 3 dimensions. The first 2 dimensions are always matching.
I want them all to be of the same shape for further processing. Example:

tensor a: (1, 10)
tensor b: (1, 10, 15)

Now my approach was to pad 'tensor a' with zeros to the shape of 'tensor b' without changing any information.

In the following snippet `feature_tensor` can be seen as `tensor a` and the `padding_reference_tensor` as `tensor b`.

For the padding i use torch.nn.functional.pad.

```
if feature_tensor.dim() == padding_reference_tensor.dim():
   padding_number = padding_reference_tensor.size()[2] - feature_tensor.size()[2]

elif feature_tensor.dim() < padding_reference_tensor.dim():
   padding_number = padding_reference_tensor.size()[2] - 1

feature_tensor = F.pad(feature_tensor, (0, padding_number), "constant", 0)
```

The case that `feature_tensor.dim() > padding_reference_tensor.dim()` can be ignored for now.

Now i'd like `feature_tensor` to be from (1,10) to (1,10,15) but instead it is (1,24).

I understand why that happened but how do I add efficiently a dimension to `feature_tensor` when it is necessary?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding does not add dimensions to a tensor but adds elements to an existing dimension. For example: Say you have a vector shaped `(3,)` with values `[1, 2, 3]` and want to multiply it by a tensor shaped `(2, 3)` If you just 0-pad it with 2 elements, you will get a tensor shaped `(5,)` with values `[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]`, which will be no good to operate with the `(2,3)` tensor.

You have two options for this:

1. Repeat the tensor across a new dimension. You can use `torch.repeat` or the more efficient [`torch.expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand.html#torch.Tensor.expand) to get the tensor

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3]]
```

which you can then operate with any other `(2, 3)` shaped tensor.

2. The most efficient and common way to do this is to convert your `(3,)` tensor to a `(1, 3)` tensor. This you can do by using [`unsqueeze()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html) method. This will add a new dimension of size 1. Now your `(1, 3)` tensor can operate with any tensor shaped `(2, 3)`. I suggest you take a look at [broadcast semantics](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#general-semantics) for more info.